# Display PHP Progress Live [Server Setting?]

Tags: php, live

well I have this script and basically it's doing a loop of stuff, now when I was running the same script on my friends server it would display the progress live, like display text as it was doing the loop.

But now for some reason on my server, it's waiting until the scripts done executing completely before displaying any data what so ever.

You guys got any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Check if your PHP settings have output buffering enabled by default: http://cz.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php

Comment: Yes, check for output buffer and perhaps look into the flush() call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
 ob_flush();
    flush();
```

After each system out (echo / print) etc ..

Answer (score 0):

Getting this to work is dependent on web server settings, php settings, and browser type and browser settings. This is what I read from lot of posts. I had this problem too and was solved by echoing whitespaces

```
echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);
echo "Your echo goes here"
```